# Titanium: How to safely add `tiapp.xml` to VCS without exposing keys

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I want to add my Titanium app to VCS.

However, I do not want to share any production keys or other important stuff that should be kept secret and thus should not added to a VCS.

Things like:

```
<property name="acs-password-development" type="string">XXXX</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-secret-development" type="string">XXXX</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-key-development" type="string">XXXX</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-development" type="string">XXXX</property>
<property name="acs-authbase-url-development" type="string">https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-base-url-development" type="string">https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-username-production" type="string">appc_app_user</property>
<property name="acs-password-production" type="string">XXX</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-secret-production" type="string">XXXX</property>
<property name="acs-oauth-key-production" type="string">XXXX</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-production" type="string">XXXX</property>
<property name="acs-authbase-url-production" type="string">https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-base-url-production" type="string">https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="appc-org-id" type="string">XXXX</property>
<property name="appc-creator-user-id" type="string">XXXX</property>
```

etc.

(Is there any other important stuff I missed out?)

How would I deal with this issue?

Comment: Check it dashboard.appcelerator.com. They should contain the keys for the application you are talking about. As for the URLs, they are same for all the projects so I think that they can be added to VCS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can use a small script to build the application with a custom file configuration per environment (it's not in VCS). For example:

- The configuration file could use the yaml format (or another one):

```
development:
    configuration_variable: value
    ...
testing:
    configuration_variable: value
    ...
production:
    configuration_variable: value
    ...
```

- The build script (you can use nodejs, python, etc) reads the configuration file and environment option to modify the tiapp.xml file. In this way you can keep out of VCS the production configuration.

To build your script, there are many libraries available in nodejs and python to modify xml files. You can check: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiapp.xml